# How to create a negated charclass pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I need a method taking a pattern as an argument and returning the negated pattern. The input pattern is always a charclass (otherwise it'd impossible). The straightforward attempt

```
public Pattern negate(Pattern p) {
    return Pattern.compile("[^" + p.pattern() + "]");
}

private void test() {
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]");
    final Pattern n = negate(p);
    System.out.println(n.matcher("0").matches());
}
```

fails because of `[` in `[^[` (unlike in `[^xyz[`) being taken literally instead of as a start of a nested charclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't nest character classes like that.

If you always know that you're getting a character class, the easiest way would be to trim the input string of its brackets:

```
public Pattern negate(Pattern p) {
    return Pattern.compile("[^" + p.pattern().substring(1));
}
```

A more robust method would be to parse the input with regular expresions... :)

Comment: It looks like you're right. Lacking the set difference operator `--` I see no possibility. Your solution doesn't work for nested charclasses, as the caret doesn't negate them.